Mount phone to film through windshield
I occasionally film backcountry drives to share with family members who aren’t mobile.

In the past, I’ve cobbled together a mount for my phone below the rear view mirror using supplies on hand. But the mount is usually precarious and rattles when going over bumps. I’m looking something sturdier.
How can I mount a phone under rear the rearview mirror so that it films through the windshield?
Samsung Galaxy; 2010 Silverado 1500

My Tacoma has a Go Pro mount next to the rear view mirror from the factory. My wife uses a suction cup mount on her sedan for a traffic cam. Lots of options out there.

I'm not sure this is really on topic here. It's not an outdoors question, and you're simply looking for a windshield phone mount.

Closed, as this is really just a shopping question.

Frame challenge:
Don't mount a phone on the car body; mount your camera on your body. I would get a GoPro (I have no affiliation or endorsement; it's simply a well known name) or similar mounted system that you can mount on your forehead (not top of head) as you provide natural stabilization of the image when you move your head to compensate for the movement of the vehicle. There are, of course, also devices for fixing cameras like the GoPro to vehicle bodies, including on the windshield. They also have image stabilization software that makes these sorts of videos easier.
There are also many options for mounting a phone on your windshield. I would do a search for "windshield galaxy mount" or similar; you should be able to get from any number of suppliers in North America (assuming that's where you are, based on the plants in the picture, I would guess northern USA/southern Canada). You would want one that has a tightening cradle for the phone, rather than a friction mount (sticky pad behind phone) for two reasons:

You don't want the cradle to obscure the phone camera(s)
You want the cradle to hold the phone securely while being bumped around, so that the phone doesn't fall down while driving.

Personally, if I were going down the phone route, I would get a dash-mounted one, so that the attachment bit is less likely to obscure the camera also.

I'm guessing you're not very tall! Even if a GoPro on my head didn't hit my van ceiling, it wouldn't see much.  OTOH a chest mount is much less stable and doesn't turn with your head; it also gets a lot of steering wheel and hands in the field of view.  There are (or used to be) cameras that mount to the side of your helmet, or I guess head, using a rubber strap.  They might be better.  But in general these sorts of camera are pretty wide-angle, and will shoot better close to the windscreen. Also then  the dirt will be out of focus

@ChrisH Perfectly average for my generation, maybe an inch/2.5 cm shorter than the average for people born this century. I was thinking forehead mounted rather than top of head, so a few cm (1-2 in) above your eyes, which should be plenty of clearance to see out the windshield for most. Edited into answer. Check out POV driving videos on youtube for what it should look like.

Here's a good one to show the set-up and how it looks at the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qFFEog_zxk. He starts the set-up at 3:25.

OK, so not just forehead-mounted but lowered into the top edge of his field of view.  Better hope it doesn't drop any further on rough ground.  Then it nicely illustrates a couple of points I was making: The first might be desirable for him, but there's a lot of car interior in the frame, reducing the amount of outdoors you can see, and much of what you can see is to the left of the car.  The other is just what I said about the dirt on the windscreen being in focus (e.g. @6:41 against the dark trees, while the dirt is in sunlight)
